# Skip user input when using anaconda with kickstart

Tags: centos, redhat, kickstart, anaconda

When I boot up the first time it always requests user input, in the case of text mode it asks me to press B to continue the installation.  I would like to provision the system with no user input.  Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens when a configuration option that the installer needs to know is missing from the kickstart file, thus the pause to ask for user input on what to do next. You might want to open the file in the GUI kickstart configurator to ensure all settings are defined.

Comment: Yup, and I would give you a point if I had the server fault reputation.  I was missing repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=http://dhcp.serverfoo.com:81/centos --cost=100

Comment: Just glad to hear it worked.